# Huge discrepancy in Azure logs for zipdeploy between files processed and files actually uploaded

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Our Jenkins build logs show that for our front end web application, we zipped 17341 files and successfully pushed them to Azure using zipdeploy.

Our Azure logs show that our last 10 deployments from zipdeploy were successful, but there seem to be huge discrepancies in the number of files that were actually processed.  Sorted by elapsed time for the deployment, here's the number of files that were processed in each deployment.

[image]

Any idea why Azure isn't processing all of the files, but still marking each deployment a success?

Answer (score 0):

Per MSFT Azure support, if you're running more than the recommended number of apps on your worker, this can happen.  In our case, the recommended number was 8 and we had 29.